# Is there any way to get primary key using record when creating tables in django_tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm trying to get the **primary key** of my table in `tables.py` using django-tables2 by using the variables `record.pk`. I supposed that `record.pk` exist originally but somehow it's not.

```py
class TableServeur(tables.Table):
    type_server = tables.Column()
    memory = tables.Column(attrs={"td": {"class": "memory"}}, verbose_name="% Mem")
    cpu = tables.Column(attrs={"td": {"class": "cpu"}}, verbose_name="% Cpu")
    port = tables.Column()
    etat = tables.Column()
    # here is the problem
    T1 = '<a class="btn" href="/update/{{record.pk}}" >Icon</a>'
    action = CustomTemplateColumn(T1)

    class Meta:
        fields = ["type_server", "cpu", "memory", "port", "etat", "action"]
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap4.html"
```

views.py

```
def cpu_view(request,nom_client):
    output = []
    liste = get_proc_output() 
    listServers = Serveurs.objects.all() # port, tp_serveur
    listNetstat = get_netstat_output() # port,pid,etat
    list_pcpu = get_proc_stat(liste) # pid,cpu,mem
    # we add percentage of cpu of each item
    for i in range(len(liste)):
        liste[i]['cpu'] = list_pcpu[i]
    # we mix and reorganise the list by their pid
    for x in liste:
        pid = x.get('pid')
        for y in listNetstat:
            if pid in y.values():
                output.append({**x,**y})    
    # we add the type of server by their port
    for i in listServers:
        for j in output:
            if i.port in j.values():
                j['type_server'] = i.type_du_serveur

    # if we have switched off server, print it with different way
    temp_list_1 = [i.type_du_serveur for i in listServers]
    temp_list_2 = [x['type_server'] for x in output]
    serveurs_eteint = list(set(temp_list_1) - set(temp_list_2))

    # 
    for j in serveurs_eteint:
        if j == k['type_server']:
            output.append({'type_server':j,'memory':'--','etat':'CLOSED'})

    for k in output:
        k['nom_client'] = nom_client
    # here we construct the table
    table = TableServeur(output)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'server/table.html', {'table': table, 'nom': nom_client, 'output': output})
```

So is there any way I can get the primary key directly when creating a table using django-tbales2?

Comment: Should you maybe have a `model = ...` statement in the `Meta` class?

Comment: Actually, i'm using a `dict` to create my table, so i don't think I need it @AKX

Comment: That's your problem then. If you use a dict, you don't have objects. Why do you expect "record.pk" to be defined? Just add a `pk` column to your data dict and use `{{pk}}`

Comment: it's kinda long and full of functions...but one thing I can say is in the `dict`, there's no key named `pk` if that's the source of the problem @dirkgroten

Comment: One thing I don't understand is how the table is created before this, i didn't put the `pk` in the dict but somehow the table is created with the `pk` values @dirkgroten

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, what do you mean "before this" and "somehow the table is created with the pk values"? Where do you see the pk values then?

Comment: if you look at the class `TableServeur` above, there is no column for a primary key because in there is no `pk` (primary key) in my `dict`, but when I render the table in the template, the primary key or the probably the id is created by itself, I wonder how it is created... sorry if you don't understand, i'm bad at explaining things @dirkgroten

Comment: that's not possible, i think you really need to show the code where you instantiate the table and pass it to the template. At least a simplified version of it.